# Check if value in selection is part of set of other values

Tags: excel

In Excel I have the following setup:

My Data (=Selection):

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
3,88,64,2,102,5,7
7,8,13,55,203,4,6
1,4,5,8,12,113,99
```

A set/pool of numbers:

```
3,7,1,55,22
```

Now I would like to check if any value in the set/pool of numbers is
in the data (selection) and color code it if so.

I believe this should be doable with conditional formatting. 
But I do not want to add a seperate conditional formatting for every number.
But rather use a formula or anything concise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data set up like this:

[image]

You can use the following approach:

- define a named range `myPool` referring to `I1:I5`
- select `A1:G3`, add conditional fomatting rule, choose `use formula to determine which cells to format` and enter:

  `=COUNTIF(myPool,A1)>0`
- choose background color and confirm

This will highlight values from `I1:I5`. To make it more universal, you can change definition of `myPool` to (adjust worksheet name):

```
=Sheet1!$I$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$I:$I,COUNTA(Sheet1!$I:$I))
```

In this case the named range will dynamically grow when you enter additional numbers in `I6`, `I7`, ...